# How can i send json data through php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

Sql Query:

```
CREATE TABLE company(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    company longtext not null,
    insurance longtext not null,
    created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

I want to send JSON data in Company and Insurance Column and the company itself is a user input that a user will tell that what combination of companies and insurance he wants . In other words i want to send 2-d Array of php encoded with json . Is it possible in Php?

Comment: (1) MySQL supports JSON datatype - so LONGTEXT is strange (2) MySQL may store any valid JSON document.

Comment: You can store it as a json string by converting it with json_encode() when you fetch tha date use json_decode($string, true) to use it again as an array. Like @Akina say MYsql databases support json type as column but if you use a Mariadb you need the json encode en decode function